# Color Bug / White is Pink everywhere

Tags: interface, color

I have this weird bug.

When I open a new scene in Blender, white is locked to slightly pink hue and the saturation cannot be pushed down. When I try to slide the saturation down, it bounces back to 0.063848. This applies to lights, materials, add-ons etc...

And the worst thing is that this is happening in 2.79 and also 2.8. I really don't know what to do about this.

Everything is in normal when I load older Blender scene from when everything worked without a problem.

[image]

Comment: what if you choose Load Factory Settings from the File menu?

Comment: now I am an idiot. It is back to normal now. Thanks!

Comment: If you reset you can't check now but if it happens again check Properties.. Render/Color Management/Display Device. If it's set to anything unexpected (e.g. something other than `sRGB` when using a standard monitor) that is most likely the cause. This has happened to me a couple times (though I have no idea how it got moved off of sRGB).